# Using Robots.txt For Finding username and Password

Tags: robots.txt

How can I find the Username and Password of a website by robots.txt?

Answer (score 2):

You can't. 
robots.txt is used to prevent cooperating web crawlers and other web robots from accessing all or part of a website which is otherwise publicly viewable.
 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard

Comment: Haha, Polish? =D

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard

Comment: @Fuji: I've corrected link ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  `robots.txt` has nothing to do with usernames or passwords.

I'm not sure what made you think the two things were related - perhaps you could edit your question to include more information?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot

`robots.txt` contains instructions to web crawlers about which directories to search and which to leave alone